# Selecting Only one value in duplicate record

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have a result like the bwlow image. now, i want to select only wireline instead of all. So, how can i select the 1st row if the all columns are same except produtc_line[image]

No, where conditions as we have other data as well

Comment: How do you define that wireless is “first” or the one you want?

Comment: Wireline is not defined at first. it's irregular but I want to take wirline as result if it's compared with ALL

Comment: And if there is *only* ALL (let's say for a different `mod_nm` value), do you want that row? If there are two rows that are not ALL, which one do you want? You need to frame your whole problem with examples and edge cases, not just two rows.

Answer (score 1):

The following is for PostgreSQL (which you tagged as well), but you could probably find something similar for SQL Server as well.

---

If you only want the row with `ALL` or *some* other row if that doesn't exist, you can use an order by with an expression and then limit the result to just one row.

```
select *
from the_table
where mod_nm = 'COST OUT MODULE'
order by case when product_line = 'ALL' then 999 else 1 end
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

This will sort the result based on product_line, and sorts the value `ALL` to the end, then only fetches the first row from that result (in SQL Server version before 2012 you would need to use the non-standard `SELECT TOP (1) ...` instead).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server, you may try with the next approach, which uses `ROW_NUMBER()` to number the rows within a partition defined by `mod_nm` column. Use `ORDER BY` clause with `CASE` expression to order rows correctly in each partition and choose an appropriate second order expression (`product_line` in the example).

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    mod_nm varchar(50),
    product_line varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO #Data 
    (mod_nm, product_line)
VALUES
    ('COST OUT MODULE', 'WireLine Services'),
    ('COST OUT MODULE', 'All'),
    ('OTHER MODULE', 'WireLine Services'),
    ('OTHER MODULE', 'WireLine'),
    ('OTHER MODULE', 'Different Product Line')
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT mod_nm, product_line
FROM (
    SELECT 
        mod_nm, 
        product_line,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY mod_nm 
           ORDER BY 
              CASE WHEN product_line = 'All' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
              product_line
        ) AS Rn
    FROM #Data
) t
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Output:

```
mod_nm          product_line
COST OUT MODULE WireLine Services
OTHER MODULE    Different Product Line
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Postgres**.

**Assuming** (since your question is incomplete):

- This table definition:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE tbl (tbl_id int, mod_nm text, product_line text)
  ```
- You want exactly *one* row per value of `mod_nm` and there can be many distinct values.
- Rows with *anything* but `product_line = 'ALL'` come first.

This would do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (mod_nm) *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  mod_nm, product_line = 'ALL'
```

The expression `product_line = 'ALL'` yields `FALSE`, `TRUE` (or `NULL`), which sorts in the given sequence in (default) ascending order. Hence, rows with anything but 'All' come first if available. See:

- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21892611/939860)

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)